# Send email from contact form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, smtp, smtpclient

I have been trying to make a contact form so it sends an email to me but I cannot get an email to send. Can anyone see if there is something I have done wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have removed my email and password for security reasons I have not just left them blank. I cannot think off what I have missed.

This is my controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Name, string EmailId, string phoneNo, string subject, string Message)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(EmailId);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("joeyoe395@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = subject;

        string userMessage = "";
        userMessage = "<br/>Name :" + Name;
        userMessage = userMessage + "<br/>Email Id: " + EmailId;
        userMessage = userMessage + "<br/>Phone No: " + phoneNo;
        userMessage = userMessage + "<br/>Message: " + Message;
        string Body = "Hi, <br/><br/> A new enquiry by user. Detail is as follows:<br/><br/> " + userMessage + "<br/><br/>Thanks";

        mail.Body = Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Email", "Password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        smtp.Send(mail);
        ViewBag.Message = "Thank you for contacting us!";

    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Error......";
    }

    return View(); 
}
```

This is my view code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact Us Form in MVC5 & MVC6 C#";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><strong>SEND EMAIL USING GMAIL ACCOUNT IN MVC</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Name :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="txtName" name="Name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Your Email id  :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="txttoaddress" name="EmailId"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Phone No :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="txtPhoneno" name="PhoneNo"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Subject :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="txtsubject" name="Subject" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Message :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="Message" id="txtmessage"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Attachment :</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" text="Send Message" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Catch the exception and debug your code to see what the problem is

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I am not the best at C#, only just learning it

Comment: Take your code and move it outside of the Try { } tag and you will get an actual error which you can share here.

Comment: The catch block should look like this `catch (Exception ex) { ... }` then use the debugger to step through your code, if there's an exception then you can inspect it and see the message. Or if you prefer put the exception message and stack trace in `ViewBag`.  But you'd be better learning how to use the debugger

Answer (score 0):

The error might occur due to following cases.

- case 1: when the password is wrong
- case 2: when you try to login from some App
- case 3: when you try to login from the domain other than your time zone/domain/computer (This is the case in most of scenarios when sending mail from code)

If you think that your credentials are correct, then please go the following link https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and enable secure less apps. So that you'll be able to login from other apps.